# generate html from java beans - at compile time

Tags: java, html

I have a bunch of Java beans. All of them are simple but some of them have more than 50 fields. So it will take a lot of time of write HTML for them.

I want to know if there is a utility (preferable command line) I can use to generate HTML forms from the Java classes.

Note that I don't need to do this dynamically or anything. I need to do this before compile time.

Something like [grails generate-views](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html) but without the GSP markup

Comment: What kind of HTML do you want to generate? Display-as-table and add/alter single instances, or something more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Another option to the ones listed by jdevelop is [Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org).
It provides several viewers of your domain objects (i.e. POJOs + some optional extras) - Apache Wicket based viewer and JAX-RS based one.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at Apache Wicket and it's tools:

https://sites.google.com/site/wicketrad/

http://wicketwebbeans.sourceforge.net/